# Изменение мета-поля, не заходя на страницу редактирования

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

WordpPress. Можно ли реализовать такой следующий функционал?
Суть:
У поста есть мета-поле со значениями 1 либо 0. Нужно вывести его в виде кнопки так, чтобы нажатие на нее переключало значение поля. Удобное изменение объектов без необходимости перехода на страницу редактирования. Если есть другие идеи, допустим, с радио кнопками, кнопкой сохранения, если нужно - предлагайте. Важно, чтобы обновление проиходило без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: как я понимаю, нужно что-то вроде http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/add-custom-column.html и навесить обработчики на AJAX

Comment: @Heidel здесь речь идет о добавлении колонки в админке. Это не то, что мне нужно. Я хочу вывести поле в archive.php с возможностью изменить его оттуда же. В любом случае, спасибо за попытку помочь.

Comment: ну так делайте по клику на кнопке аджакс-запрос на сервер, а там уже пишите функцию с необходимым набором действий

Comment: @alenkins, я понимаю, возможно, для вас это - сущий пустяк, но я в скриптах не очень силен(это мягко сказано). Если вы поможете мне с этим - я буду вам очень благодарен.

Comment: вам нужен ajax + update_post_meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общий код в `single.php` для примера. В селекте выводятся возможные значения мета-поля, при выборе любого значения на сервер летит аджакс-запрос, меняющий значение поля `"my_key"`.

```
<?php
$ajax_url = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; /* url для аджакс-запроса */
$post_id = get_the_ID(); /* id текущего поста */
$nonce = wp_create_nonce('post_id_' . $post_id); /* ключ для проверки */
$my_meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_key', true) ? get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_key', true) : 0; /* текущее значение мета-поля */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="my_select">
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php selected($my_meta, $i); ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
<div>Текущее значение <span id="my_meta"><?php echo $my_meta; ?></span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $('#my_select').on('change', function(){
            var $el = $(this),
                data = {
                    action: 'ajaxUpdateMeta', /* имя функции-обработчика на сервеной стороне */
                    meta_val: $el.val(), /* новое значение мета-поля */
                    post_id: '<?php echo $post_id; ?>',
                    nonce: '<?php echo $nonce; ?>'
                };
            $.post(
                '<?php echo $ajax_url; ?>',
                data,
                function(data){
                    $('#my_meta').text(data);
                }
            );
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Код обработчика в файле `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function ajaxUpdateMeta() {
    $metaVal = $_POST['meta_val'];
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    $action = 'post_id_' . $post_id;
    if (wp_verify_nonce($nonce, $action)) { /* проверяем, что ключ верный и обновляем значение мета-поля для переданного id поста */
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_key', $metaVal);
    }
    echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_key', true);
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxUpdateMeta', 'ajaxUpdateMeta');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxUpdateMeta', 'ajaxUpdateMeta');
```

Имейте в виду, что код примерный. Валидацию значений проводите в соответствии с требованиями вашей задачи

Comment: похоже, это должно сработать

Answer (score -1):

файл index.html(index.php)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div id='yourId'></div>
<button id="buttonId">Click me</button>

<script>
$("#buttonId").click(function() {
    num = $("#yourId").text();

    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#yourId").text(data);
    });

});
</script>
```

файл test.php (явное обновление поля в БД) или используйте update_post_meta
Замените только запросы на ваши.

```
<?php
mysql_connect('db_adress', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

$result = mysql_query('your sql to select current num');
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($row[0] == 0) { $currentNum = 1; } else { $currentNum = 0; }

$result = mysql_query('your sql query to update table set $currentNum');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo $currentNum;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я протестирую ваш код в ближайшее время. Можете объяснить, как работает этот скрипт? Здесь нет стандартных функций wordpress типа `update_post_meta()`, поэтому мне интересно. Он действительно должен работать?

Comment: создайте в блокноте файл и сохраните с расширением .html и увидите его работу... а что обяснять там все стандартные функции.... берите любую функцию вбивайте в гугл и читайте...  wordPress этоже cms а не язык программировния...все его методы наподобие update_post_meta()  - выполняют php код который в конечном счете генерирует HTML, который вы и видите в браузере, нажатие на кнопку происходит у вас на компьютере а не на удаленном сайте...т.е вы по сути работаете с HTML кодом...

Comment: Я понял вас. Но ваш скрипт не сохранит значение поля в базу данных. А мне нужно именно это.

Comment: Изменил ответ...

Comment: Проверяли?  должно работать..